# "More functional" "accessor" for collections in C#

Tags: c#, collections, setter, getter, accessor

Now I have a collection: `Dictionary<string, List<string>> dictionary`.

For some reason, now I want to "project/map" a part of it to other collections, sort of like using it as backing field, and create different accessors for this collection.

Like `List<string> keys` corresponds to the keys of this dictionary, or `Dictionary<string, string> firstItems` corresponds to a dictionary uses the source dictionary keys as key, and first item in values in source dictionary as values.

This could be partially done by adding behavior in the getter/setter of `keys` and `firstItems`. When we call `keys`, we get keys from `dictionary`; or when we call `keys = whateverTheListIs`, `dictionary` may perform certain behavior as designed too.

But I would also like to have a "more functional" "accessor", for example, when we call `firstItems.Add(aString, anotherString)`, we add an entry to the `dictionary` too; or when we call `keys.Remove(yetAnotherString)`, we remove the entry in the `dictionary`.

Is their any way I can do that?

Edit:

Here is the scenario (of course you may change it, it's just for explanation):

```
public class Projection
{
  private Dictionary<string, List<string>> dictionary; //"backing field"

  public List<string> keys;
  public Dictionary<string, string> firstItems;
}

public static void DoSomething()
{
  Projection projection = new Projection();
  //Supposed to modify projection.dictionary too
  projection.keys = new List<string>();
  projection.keys.Add("A new Key");
}
```

Comment: You can implement your own collection deriving from IDictionary, then add more functionality inside the .Add / .Remove calls.

Comment: It's probably better to consider the `keys` and `firstItems` as read only and use the original `dictionary` when you want to make changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own `Dictionary` with inheritance :

```
class CustomDictionary<TKey,TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    // Implement the interface IDictionary here

    public void Add(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        // create your logic
    }
}
```

You can use composition :

```
class CustomDictionary<TKey,TValue>
{
    private Dictionary<TKey,TValue> _dictionary;

    public void Add(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        // create your logic
        _dictionary.Add();
    }
}
```

And my favorite way, you can use both :

```
class CustomDictionary<TKey,TValue> : IDictionary<TKey,TValue>
{
    private Dictionary<TKey,TValue> _dictionary;

    // Implement the interface IDictionary here
    // send the logic to your private Dictionary

    public void Add(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
         // create your logic
        _dictionary.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
    }
}
```

If you want to inherit directly from a `Dictionary`, you will face a problem. You cannot override the method `Add()` because its not a `virtual` method. A solution would be to hide it with the keyword `new`.

```
class CustomDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    public new void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        // create your logic
        base.Add(key, value);
    }

    public void Add(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        this.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
    }
}
```